# Wordpress categories list with jquery load()

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

A "select" element is created by a wordpress plugin (PHP) and I want to add  elements in it with .load() function of jQuery.

jQuery:

```
$("#ugc-input-post_category").load("../wp-content/themes/anim-theme/post-category.php");
```

post-category.php:

`<?php
  echo '<h1>TEST</h1>';
  $categories = get_categories();
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) :
    echo '<option value="' . $category->term_id . '">' . $category->name . '</option>';
  endforeach;
 ?>`

The echo function that returns "TEST" works and the "h1" element appears in the "select" element, but not the different categories that should be generated by the loop. However, when I add the PHP code in the PHP code of a page, it works and the category list is generated. So I think it's an issue with the load() function.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: you can't put `h` tags in a `<select>` .... only `<optgroup>` or `<option>`

Comment: Path is all wrong too. Read up on how to use ajax in wordpress. You need an `action` and use the proper ajax endpoint and registered methods

Answer (score 0):

When the code is included to the normal page,  WordPress use data derived from the page that was loaded through WordPress Main Loop, so they can know which data to take, based on the page you are displaying.

But when you took load from the separate file,  they didn't have data prepared for them, so it's unable to display the data correctly.

So the next question is you want to use Ajax method to load the page or not?

If not,  use PHP 'include'  instead so it can generate date since server's load.

If using Ajax,  write an Ajax function that return 'json' and use jQuery to display them.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The PHP should generate html into an HTML element that is generated with a wordpress plugin. So I can't use PHP 'include' I think.